# unhable to get data from store in JS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vuex, apollo-client

I'm trying to get a token state that's fetch from an API and stored in VUEX store. 
Unfortunatly,I always add an error into my console about graphQLClient.js who explain that the store.state is undefined.
(exact error code : "TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__store_index**.a is undefined"). I precise that the App.vue contains two functions inside the export :

```
beforeCreate() {
   this.$store.dispatch("getToken");
},
beforeMount() {
   this.$store.dispatch("getClients");
}
```

I noticed that beforeCreate should be called before beforeMount but that's not true, I've putted some console.log() everywhere and it appears that beforeMount() is called before one time.

store/index.js :

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import token from "./modules/token";
import client from "./modules/client";

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    client,
    token
  }
});
```

store/module/client.js

```js
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import graphqlClient from "../../utils/graphqlClient";
export default {
  state: {
    client: null,
    clientList: []
  },

  mutations: {
    ADD_CLIENT(state, client) {
      state.client = client;
    },
    GET_CLIENT_LIST(state, clientList) {
      state.clientList = clientList;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async getClients({ commit }) {
      console.log(store.state.token.token);
      const response = await graphqlClient.query({
        query: gql`
          query {
            getClients(offset: 0, limit: 20) {
              id
            }
          }
        `
      });
      commit("GET_CLIENT_LIST", response.data.getClients);
    }
  },
  getters: {}
};
```

store/module/token.js :

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import { port, host, userLogin, userPassword } from "../../utils/config";

export default {
    state: {
      token: "PasDeToken"
    },

    // mutations
    mutations: {
      GET_TOKEN(state, token) {
        state.token = token;
      }
    },

    // actions
    actions: {

      async getToken({ commit }) {
        const response = await Axios({
          url: `http://${host}:${port}/getToken?login=${userLogin}&   password=${userPassword}`,
          method: "get"
        });
        commit("GET_TOKEN", response.data.token);
      }
    },

    // getters
    getters: {
      gimmeMyToken: state => () => {
        console.log("Im ready");
        return state.token;
      }
    }
  
};
```

utils/graphqlClient.js :

```js
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { port, host } from "./config";
import store from "../store/index";
export default new ApolloClient({
  
  link: new HttpLink({

    uri: `http://${host}:${port}/graphql`,
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.token.token}`
    }
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

**EDITED 07/18:**

I change some things, change Apollo Client for full Axios request plugin and it's better but not working actually. So the graphQlClient.js is fully commented, and now in Client.js I use it :

The code :

```
await Axios.post(
    "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    {
      query: `query {
      getClients(offset: 0, limit: 20){
        id
      }
    }`
    },
    { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.token.token}`}}
  ).then((response) => {

    console.log(response.data);
    commit("GET_CLIENT_LIST", response.data.getClients);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(store.state.token.token);
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The error code :

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dpbiI6IkJsdWVrYW5nbyIsImlhdCI6MTU2MzQzODI4NywiZXhwIjoxNTYzNDQxODg3fQ.DR_Ok-ODsVDGBI1mIbpzAAXPfIXS8hmWiOTvDI12Fs0 client.js:64
Error: "Request failed with status code 400"
createError createError.js:16
settle settle.js:17
handleLoad xhr.js:59
```

Comment: Did you try removing `console.log(store.state.token.token)`?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't change anything.. I've tried without all console.log cause I know that it can't change the "order" but that's not the reason why it's not working..